# Installing mcrypt extension on CentOS 6

Tags: php, centos6, php-mcrypt

I am trying to install the mcrypt extension on my CentOS 6 VPS. I have done the EPEL rpm and then updated everything. Now, I keep getting this error and I've also installed php-api.

```
[root@vps ~]# yum -y install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.raystedman.net
 * epel: mirror.oss.ou.edu
 * extras: mirror.teklinks.com
 * updates: bay.uchicago.edu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.1.6-5.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php-api = 20041225
           Installed: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (@updates)
               php-api = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-api = 20090626
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

AmI skipping/missing something important? Please don't down vote this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed the *wrong* EPEL RPM.

You are running CentOS 6, but you installed the epel-release RPM for EPEL 5.

Remove it and install the RPM for EPEL 6.

Comment: When trying wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm then doing yum install epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm it throws this error at me: 

Setting up Install Process
Examining epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm: epel-release-6-8.noarch
epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: You didn't remove the existing package first, as I already said.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/H0dC3wt.png

Comment: That image says nothing about whether you removed the old `epel-release` package.

Comment: Am I installing EPEL 6-8?

Comment: Yes, but only after you remove the old package.